# how to get user who completed user task in camunda

Tags: bpmn, camunda

I want to get username of user who completed a user task in a camunda process.

for example consider a BMPN with only 2 steps , first is a user task and second is a externalTask. for a invocation of this BPMN if a user completes first user task then i should be able get its username in second externalTask.

I did not find any process variable being set in camunda after user task is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user who completed a user task in Camunda can be stored using a Task Listener. To set this up:

1. Select the user task where you wish to record the data
2. In the properties panel go to the 'Listeners' tab and click + in the 'Task Listener' section
3. Set the 'Event Type' to 'complete'
4. Set the 'Listener Type' to 'Expression'
5. Enter the expression:

   ```
    ${task.execution.setVariable('taskCompletedBy', task.assignee)}
   ```

When the user task is completed the task listeners expression will be executed. The expression takes the username from `task.assignee`, then uses the `setVariable()` function on the execution scope `task.execution` to store it in a variable. As the variable is stored on the execution scope it's available to the rest of the process. You can then use the variable as with any other variables in later user / service tasks.

Comment: While this is true, let me add: Camunda does not force you to assign or claim a task prior to completing it (if you use a custom tasklist or the rest api). But: If you have a security scope (such as Spring Security) you can query the logged in user and store it as task assignee.